# Item Renderer having trouble updating

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe, mxml, itemrenderer

I have a list `ItemRenderer` that has 2 states. When it initializes, I set it to 1 state and listen for an event that switches it to state 2.

```
protected function onCreationComplete(event:FlexEvent):void{
   currentState = "state1";
   addEventListener(CustomEvent.Event1, switcherfunc);
}

protected function switcherfunc(event:FlexEvent):void{
   currentState = "state2";
}
```

The difference between the 2 states is that I hide/show some labels.

The problem is that it doesn't work. I still see the visual of the old state, even though if I `Alert.show(currentState)`, it shows the correct state name.

I've tried adding the line `invalidateDisplayList();` inside the switch function but still no luck.

```
protected function switch(event:FlexEvent):void{
   currentState = "state2";
   invalidateDisplayList();
}
```

What am I doing wrong. Any ideas how I can get this ItemRenderer to really update?

Comment: Are you using `switch` as a function name - it's a reserved keyword - this shouldn't even compile.

Comment: It's a fictitious name just to demonstrate. My function is something else.

Comment: Can you provide us some runnable code?  What event does your 'switch' handler listen for?  Are you sure the event handler is firing? Are you listening to the DataChange event to accommodate for renderer recycling?

Comment: @Flextras, I'll try to produce a runnable reduced sample. Will post back soon.